# Using the Mapdeck library in R Shiny, is there a way to capture the view state of the map for use server side?

Tags: r, shiny, mapdeck

I am using `mapdeck` in an `R Shiny` Project. When the user pans/pitches/rotates/zooms the map I would like to know what the current view state is, so that I can use the new values of `lat`, `lon`, `pitch`, `bearing`, `zoom` on the server side.

I know I can use `show_view_state = TRUE` in the main `mapdeck` call, so is there a way to capture these values? I'd like the current view state (as displayed on the map when I use `show_view_state = TRUE`) to be captured into a variable on the server side code which I can use and manipulate.

Comment: you can observe `input$map_view_change`, `input$map_drag_start`, `input$map_drag`, `input$map_drag_end` and `input$map_resize`.  (where "map" is the `outputId` of your map)